# Chart.js stepsize with multiple yAxis scales

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I'm trying to get horizontal grid lines in my chart with multiple y-axis scales
Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MartijnDx/pf2tqk3b/7/) for what I have

According to documentation, I should add stepSize to the `scales` > `yAxis` > `ticks` 
[Chart.js Doc](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/linear.html#step-size) 
But It not clear to me how to do this with multiply yAxis scales

What I get:
[image]
What I want:
[image]

Comment: Gridlines are drawn by default, but the ticks `max` and `min` values appear to be reversed. This causes chart.js to only draw the first and last tick.

Comment: "ticks max and min values appear to be reversed" Thanks for pointing me on this, this is indeed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to timclutton,

The min an max where reversed..

```
"ticks": {
    "max": 0,
    "min": 14,
    "stepSize": 7
}
```

**should be:**

```
"ticks": {
    "max": 14,
    "min": 0,
    "stepSize": 7
}
```